# Find the eclipse focal point

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

> A conic with equation
>   $$
> a x^2 + b y^2 = c
> $$
>   has two focus points, where $a=4$, $b=24$ and $c=65$. One of those focus points has a positive *x*-coordinate. To two decimal places, what is the value of that positive *x*-coordinate?

I got the answer as 14.83, seems a bit too big is that right?
The above answer is according to this in my textbook
[image]

[image]

Comment: title:"Just convert this to radians?"    
the question seems to be asking for a coordinate, not an angle...

Comment: @Navin Tks for pointing that out my old question was in my browsers cache, changed the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the ellipse in standard form. Start from $4x^2+24y^2=65$. Divide through by $65$. We get $\frac{4}{65}x^2+\frac{24}{65}y^2=1$.

This is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, where $a^2=\frac{65}{4}$ and $b^2=\frac{65}{24}$. Finally, you want $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

Your intuition is right: this is substantially smaller than your answer.  To two decimal places, I get $3.68$.

Comment: This is an elipse in standard position so the eccentricity is  squareroot(1- (a^2/b^2). Correct?

Comment: Also take note the question is asking for focal point

Comment: I found the $x$-coordinate of the focal point with positive $x$-coordinate, as the question asks. The eccentricity is not $a^2/b^2$, it is $\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}$.  If your book/notes do not have the relevant formulas, I am sure you can find them in the wikipedia article on the ellipse, there must be one!

Comment: andre please see my textbook picture, in the original post. If I am wrong please let me know. You and I agree to certain extent but the eccentricity I am not sure that is the formula that you want me to use

Comment: That is equivalent to what I wrote. But I guess if you follow the book, you will first find $e$, which is $\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$ (mine was different but equivalent) and then you will multiply by $a$. You will get $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$. Anyway, same answer. Eccentricity is about $0.91287$.

Comment: I agree with you on the eccentricity. But my 14.83 for focal point is still wrong?

Comment: Yes it is. Remember (if you want to use formula in book, which is more trouble than what I used) that $a=\sqrt{65/4}$. I just figured out what you did wrong. You used $a=65/4$, and it is $a^2$ which is $65/4$. So $a$ is about $4.031$. By the way, you really should change the title, it will mislead people using the search engine.

Comment: ah yes now i understand updated my question with full working, u always got some tricks up your sleeve. :)